# Embedded Jetty 9 takes too long to respond to first request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, jetty, embedded-jetty

We have a spring MVC project(really a big & old monolith) which we currently deploy in Tomcat server. Now I'm trying to use embedded Jetty instead of tomcat ( there is no other code changes made other than Jetty changes)

After moving to jetty , the very first request or the request aft long time without a load takes too much time to respond, it usually times out .

Jetty response time for first request is approx. 2 secs  ( which gets reduced for further requests)

where as tomcat take approx. 300milliseconds for 1st request

And on load test(100 request per sec) as well,
System load spikes for jetty , hence the CPU utilisation peaks till 60 to 65% for first few seconds then drops to 30%

whereas tomcat is able to take the load gracefully, it always maintains the 30% of CPU utilisation.

I m using `ServerConnector` as connector  & `queuedThreadPool with min: 50 , max:500 , queuesize: 6000`

tried with different pool , queue sizes, but no luck

Is there something i can change to get rid of this behaviour?

I m using jetty `9.4.48.v20220622`

My Jetty code

```
            final String WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION = "webapp";

            WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
            context.setContextPath("/");
            URL webAppDir = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION);
            if (webAppDir == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No %s directory was found into the jar file", WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION));
            }
            context.setResourceBase(webAppDir.toURI().toString());
            context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
 
            ThreadPool jettyThreadPool = new QueuedThreadPool(50,200);


            ....
```

Comment: I would try to start the web application in a stand-alone Jetty to see if there are the same performance problems as with the embedded Jetty. If not, then it might be due to how the Jetty is embedded.

Comment: You can also try to activate the Jetty debug logging like so: `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG`

Comment: To check the Jetty configuration at runtime, you can use [org.eclipse.jetty.serverServer#dump()](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#dump(java.lang.Appendable,java.lang.String)).

Comment: [Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958), you should be upgrading to Jetty 10 or Jetty 11 or even Jetty 12 at this point. -

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to render help - things missing: how you setup your Embedded Jetty (the code)? what specs/technologies your webapp uses? what parts/modules/jars of Jetty you are using?

Comment: Please detail your timing.  It's a bit confusing in your question.  Eg: Are you timing from start of the JVM to first response complete? or when the server announces the webapp deployed to first response complete? or start of the request to end of the response? or variations of above.

Comment: After i deploy the jar(with embedded jetty) i make the very first call to the server. it takes around 2 secs , then it gradually reduces. 

And in the morning (no load throughout the night) if i trigger load, the cpu spikes with jetty 

I suspect Jetty is doing some lazy loading , which is causing this.

Comment: its a Spring MVC application and We still use Java 8 , so Jetty 11 is not an option

Comment: Mixing `WebAppContext` and `context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);` is a bad idea, you are causing all of your server libraries to also be scanned on deployment.  If you use Jetty 10 with Spring MVC (not Jetty 11) then you'll be able to control which libraries are actually scanned (from a servlet spec point of view), along with better WebApp Configuration (which you are apparently not doing).  Keep in mind that NOTHING in Jetty is default or included, it's modular and everything is optional (even the server!), this is why I asked for the list of technologies (libs/specs) that you are using.

Comment: Are u suggesting to use quickstart module? 

And the service have spring MVC , hibernate , written in java , scala , uses aspectjwaver and what not (It was written a decade ago)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252413/discussion-between-jeevi-and-joakim-erdfelt).

Comment: @vanje I tried enabling debug logs , server dump.
i noticed tat all jars are scanned by sun.misc.launcher$appclassloader classer loader , even if i set setParentLoaderPriority(false) other than that i didnt find any information.